# Handle multiple MySQL databases that are on the same server with ORM Prisma

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, prisma

I'm starting a project with ORM Prisma and I need to manipulate different databases depending on the user that makes the request, all databases are MySQL but they are on the same server, does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: This is currently not natively supported in Prisma. However, there  is a workaround that you could consider: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443#issuecomment-630679118